# How to create Trailing 12 month date parameter in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

Is it possible to create trailing 12 month date parameter? I want to be able to choose Month-Year, so it display data till the end of that chosen Month-Year 12 months back.

Something like that on a picture below.

Do I need to create some date measures for that?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: It's definitely possible, but the best way to do it will depend on how you have things set up. You'll likely need to write a measure with some time intelligence function like `DATESBETWEEN`. More details from you will help someone answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use the Relative Date slicer & filter feature built into Power BI. It can cater to that requirements E.g. Last - 12 - Months (Calendar)

https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-desktop-slicer-filter-date-range/

No modeling preparation is needed - it is set in the report page design.